# How to change image in a collection view cell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView cell with imageview.The thing is that I want to change the image of the cell when the cell is selected.Can any one help me?

I tried the following.But it is not working.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"myCell";

GallaryCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.MarkImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mark.jpg"];
}
```

Comment: what is cell.MarkImg??

Comment: It is just a UIImageView.

Comment: ok so you designed that imageview in storyboard?

Comment: did you check image name is correct or not with extension as well?

Comment: Image extension and name are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing

```
GallaryCell *cell=  (GallaryCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.MarkImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mark.jpg"];
```

Instead of

```
GallaryCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.MarkImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mark.jpg"];
```

in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Writing `cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will give you exact item to be selected